# Check Input Valid Character

Tags: c

I'm pretty new to C and am in the middle of writing a "checker" code. It basically will read input and then check one by one whether the input consist of alphabet or there are either number or bad characters exist ($%^&*).

So let's say if I input `"$#@$#%^"` and ask this program to check, it will print `bad input detected`. If I input `ASDFASDFASDF`, it will print `no bad input detected`.

I could think of the `bad` way to do this because it is literally hardcoded. It looks like this:

**Assumption: all the input characters going to be in UPPERCASE**

```
int badIntCheck(char c) {
    switch (c) {
        case 'A': return 0;
        case 'B': return 0;
        case 'C': return 0;
        ............ // continues till 'Z'
        default : return 1;
    }
}

//then followed by

for (i = 0; i < strlen(inputMe)-1; i++) {
           if (badIntCheck(inputMe[i]) == 1) {
                printf ("bad input detected!")
            }
        }
```

Those several lines of code is working, but I just don't feel `effective and efficient`. So I decided to create a short code, however it doesnt seem to work. It looks like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < strlen(inputMe)-1; i++ ) {
        int var = inputMe[i];
        if (isalpha(var) == 0) {
            error ("bad input detected!");
        }
    }
```

Is there something wrong with this short `for` loop? I found it more efficient if I just use the help of `isalpha()` function that could detect whether argument is alphabet or not.

Anybody could give suggestion or input why this isn't working? Thank you.

Comment: Never do this `for (i = 0; i < strlen(inputMe)-1; i++ )`, just do this `size_t length = strlen(inputMe); for (i = 0 ; i < length - 1 ; ++i)` or `for (i = 0 ; ((inputMe[i] != '\0') && (inputMe[i + 1] != '\0')) ; ++i)`, although it seems that

Comment: I don't see any problem other than what above comment addresses . And then condition in loop should be `i < strlen(inputMe)`  ,otherwise you would not check the last character .

Comment: @iharob is `isalpha()` detect uppercase or lowercase alphabet?

Comment: @ameyCU do you know it? ^^

Comment: @coava Yes , it can check both upper and lower case alphabets

Comment: Do I see right that you are inputting lower case and only switching on UPPER CASE.  lookup toupper()

Comment: @markshancock ah yeah I forgot to tell that assumption is the input always in capital letter (UPPER CASE)

Comment: @coava Your desciption says "If I input dasklfjeiwkldasflasj"